# Случайно удалил таблицу phpmyadmin

Tags: linux, email, phpmyadmin

Сегодня произошёл казус.
Вместо нажатия крестика, что бы удалил строку, я выделил строку и удалил таблицу.
Помогите, таблица очень важная :( Что мне делать?

Comment: Учится делать [бэкапы](https://habr.com/ru/company/croc/blog/230153/)

Comment: таблица хранится в виде нескольких файлов. при удалении они удаляются с диска. Так что только средствами восстановления файлов в файловой системе. А файлы, да еще с их именами вы уже не найдете.